# Any documentation for $^I in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, file-io, special-variables

I have used `$^I` in a perl script to search and replace conditionally. I want to know whether `$^I` makes a copy of the file in the buffer and write backs entire buffer back to file after processing the buffer or it does in line editing.

The code is as follows

```
$^I = "";
my $flag = 0;

while ($line = <>) {
    if($line=~ m/some string/i) {
        $flag = 1;
    }
    if(!$flag) {
        $line =~ s/string/replace/g;
    } 
}

print $line;
```

Comment: [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#\*-i\*[\_extension\_]) has information on the usage of the `-i` switch, which is what the `$^I` variable concerns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> $INPLACE_EDIT
>
> $^I
>
> The current value of the inplace-edit extension. Use
> undef to disable inplace editing. Mnemonic: value of -i switch.

From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches):

> -i[extension]
>
> specifies that files processed by the <> construct are to be edited in-place. It does this by renaming the input file,
> opening the output file by the original name, and selecting that
> output file as the default for print() statements. The extension, if
> supplied, is used to modify the name of the old file to make a backup
> copy, following these rules:
>
> If no extension is supplied, and your
> system supports it, the original file is kept open without a name
> while the output is redirected to a new file with the original
> filename. When perl exits, cleanly or not, the original file is
> unlinked.